# Will Spark be able to perform "order By" on a dataframe? If the size of dataframe is larger than the executors memory

Tags: sorting, pyspark, sql-order-by

I had one doubt regarding spark "order By" clause. I am not sure what will happen if we perform
"order By" in a dataframe which is larger than one executor and driver memory. I searched it online
but i didn't get satisfacory result and i do not the flexibility to check it myself.
Can someone please help me on this? I know that,
When we execute an "order by" operation on a DataFrame, Spark performs a global sort operation,
which involves shuffling and redistributing data across multiple partitions.
This means that the data is divided into partitions, and each partition is sorted
individually. Then, Spark merges the sorted partitions to produce the final sorted output.

For this to happen spark needs to collect all the partition into one executer. Now,
if the executers memory is lesser than the total data. will spark be able to order it?
will it use spill to do the "order by" operation? or it will throw us OOM error.

i didn't have flexibility to try this on my own. So, can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spark will still be able to sort a DataFrame if its size exceeds a single executor memory. [Here is a post from Databricks](https://web.archive.org/web/20230507005656/https://www.databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html) describing a Spark benchmark during which a Petabyte of data was sorted.

You have correctly described that Spark shuffles the data and does local sorting. But it does not collect the sorted partitions in one executor unless you tell it to do so by, for example, calling `collect()` on the DataFrame. The sorted data can be written to a storage in the correct order by writing the individual sorted partitions in the correct order. Spark knows this order, because it is determined during the execution of the distributed sorting.